# Interesting ASK from Android Studio

Tags: android

This is a question - in my application, the Admob block loads only 3-4 minutes after launch. How to make a priority launch to block the download for a couple of seconds, and then everything else??
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.usa.news.twenty.four.seven 
Application

This is a question - in my application, the Google Admob block loads only 3-4 minutes after launch. How to make a priority launch to block the download for a couple of seconds, and then everything else??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Rather than link to your app which may be mistaken for a spam post, you should detail how you have integrated Admob into your app. Show code and any notable logcat messages.